# How to set default hg merge tool?

Tags: merge, mercurial, repository

Using Mercurial I'm used to merge branches using built in merge tool like this :

```
hg merge --tool :merge
```

How to set `--tool :merge` as default *in .hgrc* in order to just use `hg merge`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding the following lines to your `~/.hgrc`:

```
[ui]
merge = :merge
```

Comment: ...if `:merge` is known and described in `MergeTools.rc` or in any other place in `[merge-tools]` section...

Comment: Well, I tested it with a vanilla 3.5 Mercurial setup before answering to be sure and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes. But I want to repeat from `hg help merge-tools` (and fix myself): "If it is the name of a tool in the merge-tools configuration, its configuration is used. Otherwise the specified tool must be executable by the shell."